# Cypher and query templates / string substitution

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I worked a lot with MyBatis and I used very often string substitution to write less distinct queries: there, you can use #{} for PARAMETERS and ${} for plain string substitution (e.g. I want that a section of the query is calculated at runtime by the business logic).

Now, I would like to do the same in a Cypher repository in Spring (ReactiveNeo4jRepository): I have a very complex query, and I would define at runtime a section of a statement, that can have 2 different "versions" for privileged and unprivileged users. This is only a small section of a very complex statement, and so it would be much better than defining two different queries.

But I can't find anything similar to MyBatis string substitution... is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Have you considered using the CypherDSL? https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/cypher-dsl
It is not a string substitution but should allow, what you want to do (plus it also let's you extract parts to be reused).

Comment: @meistermeier yes I'm experimenting with it, but my query is very complex and I'm struggling... maybe there is no alternative I fear.